# Correct terminology for if-blocks

Tags: terminology, parsing, computer-science

I am using lex/yacc to parse a simple language which allows 'if blocks':

```
IF something
   something
  [ELSE IF something][ELSE]
END IF
```

and also other nested logic under a 'DEFINE' statement:

```
DEFINE something
  something
  something else
END DEFINE
```

I am in need of a common term to refer to these blocks (as the name of a container class). I have thought of `Flow Control` but it does not seem to correctly capture the intent...?

Comment: If-Statements, Loops, try-catch-finally, switch tables and gotos are `control structures`. Does that fit? I have never seen a define block, though. What language is that from?

Comment: It's a custom language for some simulation software input file. Apparently based on VBA macros. Control structure works well. If you add it as an answer I can accept it

Comment: A type/class definition or a function body can be seen as define blocks.

Comment: Collectively, any *control structure* that involves a condition (including loops) is called a [***branch.***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my best knowledge, `control structures` is the term used for if statements, loops, try-catch-finally, switch tables and gotos in C-like languages.

Answer (score 2):

There are three fundamental programming constructs in Computer Science; these are [Sequence, Selection and Iteration](http://www.101computing.net/sequencing-selection-iteration/).  These are Computer Science terms and apply across actual languages.

So in this case your `IF` is a Selection and your `DEFINE` is a sequence.

Comment: is this merely your opinion or you can back it up somehow?

Comment: What about Occam _PAR_ instruction, or bash pipe ?

Comment: Interesting thoughts and I'm sure such terms will come in useful elsewhere, but unfortunately it doesn't provide a common term for both types of blocks I asked for

Comment: @gnat It is a Computer Science 101 topic since I did my CS degree 20 years ago ;)   goo.gl/ms23Wd

Comment: wonder how readers of this answer are expected to find that out